# Take URL to open larger map from iFrame?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, dom, iframe

I want to get a link to open a larger map from the iFrame URL:

```
<iframe 
src='https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d414225.88930329087!2d14.068999827954114!3d46.99590051638977!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x47707345308f7e65%3A0x687eb6df8c618d2b!2sKlagenfurt%2C%20Austria!5e0!3m2!1sen!2srs!4v1643793775072!5m2!1sen!2srs' 
style='border:0;' allowfullscreen='' loading='lazy'></iframe>
```

This URL from iframe to open in a new tab is invalid :

```
https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d414225.88930329087!2d14.068999827954114!3d46.99590051638977!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x47707345308f7e65%3A0x687eb6df8c618d2b!2sKlagenfurt%2C%20Austria!5e0!3m2!1sen!2srs!4v1643793775072!5m2!1sen!2srs
```

I tried to take the URL from iFrame :

[image]

But in website mounting time, JS cannot read iFrame DOM... Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You should read what the response from [your URL](https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d414225.88930329087!2d14.068999827954114!3d46.99590051638977!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x47707345308f7e65%3A0x687eb6df8c618d2b!2sKlagenfurt%2C%20Austria!5e0!3m2!1sen!2srs!4v1643793775072!5m2!1sen!2srs) already tells you:

> The Google Maps Embed API must be used in an iframe.

As you can see in the example in the [Google Maps Embed API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/get-started) docs:

```js
<iframe
  width="600"
  height="450"
  style="border:0"
  loading="lazy"
  allowfullscreen
  src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=API_KEY
    &q=Space+Needle,Seattle+WA">
</iframe>
```

You're missing the `?key=API_KEY` part. So, set up an API key as described on the website, and you're good to go.

Comment: Other options?? :)

Comment: No, unfortunately not. But it's simple to setup and free, as you can read here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/map-generator

Answer (score 1):

The right solution is to **use the Google Maps API**. However, if you need to parse data from this URL, it is possible. URL contains lat and lng so you can (somehow) recreate target URL. The subsequent solution is only a **rough example** and is not production ready:

```js
const url = 'https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d414225.88930329087!2d14.068999827954114!3d46.99590051638977!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x47707345308f7e65%3A0x687eb6df8c618d2b!2sKlagenfurt%2C%20Austria!5e0!3m2!1sen!2srs!4v1643793775072!5m2!1sen!2srs';
const partOne = url.split('2d');
const partTwo = partOne[1].split('!3d');
const partThree = partTwo[1].split('!');
const lng = partTwo[0];
const latAndZ = partTwo[1].split('!')[0];
const z = latAndZ[latAndZ.length - 1]
const lat = latAndZ.slice(0,-1);
const result = `https://www.google.com/maps/@${lat},${lng},${z}z`;
console.log(result);
```

Comment: This is what I want, but, not working very well... Did you know why?